# Math.pow(2,63) - 1 == Math.pow(2,63) - 512 is TRUE

Tags: java, double

I thought this was kind of interesting:

```
System.out.println(  (long)(Math.pow(2,63) - 1) == Long.MAX_VALUE); // true
System.out.println(  (long)(Math.pow(2,63) - 5) == Long.MAX_VALUE); // true 
System.out.println(  (long)(Math.pow(2,63) - 512) == Long.MAX_VALUE); // true
System.out.println(  (long)(Math.pow(2,63) - 513) == Long.MAX_VALUE); // false
```

The last three lines should print `false`, but in fact only the last one, where I subtracted `513` gave the correct answer.

**Why is 512/513 the breaking point for the inaccuracy?** The only connection I could make to that is that 512 is half of a kilobyte.

---

I know that the cause of this is the `double` inaccuracy which stems from `Math.pow(int, int)` returning a `double`

I tried this with [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and this is what I got:

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("2");

System.out.println(  (b.pow(63).longValue() - 1) == Long.MAX_VALUE  ); // true
System.out.println(  (b.pow(63).longValue() - 5) == Long.MAX_VALUE  ); // false
System.out.println(  (b.pow(63).longValue() - 512) == Long.MAX_VALUE  ); // false
System.out.println(  (b.pow(63).longValue() - 513) == Long.MAX_VALUE  ); // false
```

Comment: Simpler example: `double d = Long.MAX_VALUE; System.out.println(d-512 == d); System.out.println(d-513 == d);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of floating point rounding. A double has effectively 53 bits of significand, so in the 2^63 range consecutive doubles are separated by 1024. 512 is the most you can subtract and still round up. Subtracting 513 is over half way to the next double down, and rounds down.

This program demonstrates the issue:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double maxValue = (double)Long.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(maxValue));
    double nextDown = Math.nextAfter(maxValue, 0);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(nextDown));
    System.out.println(maxValue-nextDown);
  }
}
```

It prints:

```
9223372036854775808
9223372036854774784
1024.0
```

showing the 1024 gap between the double equivalent of Long.MAX_VALUE and the next double in the zero direction.

Answer (score 2):

The internal representation of a `double` uses 52 bits to store the significand.  That means that any number represented by a `double` has a form like

```
1.ddddddddddddddddddddddd x 2 ^ n
  ^^ 52 zeroes or ones ^^
```

When you convert a number in some other form to a double, you'll actually get the closest number that fits this format.

Now, the number `2 ^ 63 = 9223372036854775808` has an exact `double` representation, because it can be stored as

```
1.00000000000000000000000 x 2 ^ 63
  ^^ 52 zeroes         ^^
```

and the number `2 ^ 63 - 2 ^ 10 = 9223372036854774784` also has an exact `double` representation.  It is

```
1.11111111111111111111111 x 2 ^ 62
  ^^ 52 ones           ^^
```

Obviously, there is no number in between these two that can be represented exactly by a `double`.

Now,

- `Long.MAX_VALUE = 2 ^ 63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807`.  The closest number to this that can be represented exactly by a double is `2 ^ 63 = 9223372036854775808`.
- `2 ^ 63 - 5 = 9223372036854775803`.  Again, the closest number to this that can be represented exactly by a double is `2 ^ 63 = 9223372036854775808`.
- `2 ^ 63 - 512 = 9223372036854775296`.  This is exactly halfway between `9223372036854775808` and `9223372036854774784`.  So Java has to choose one of these two values, to represent `9223372036854775296` as a `double`.  It rounds up - that is, it chooses the higher number.
- `2 ^ 63 - 513 = 9223372036854775295`.  The closest number to this that can be represented exactly by a double is `2 ^ 63 - 2 ^ 10 = 9223372036854774784`.  Finally, we have a number that has a **different** `double` representation from `Long.MAX_VALUE`.